# Swift - Map to different type

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

Suppose that I have a text and an array of NSRanges. From that, I want to produce an array of substrings. What I would like to do is to use a simple map function and get done with it:

```
let substrings = ranges.map { return (text as NSString).substringWithRange($0) }
```

Swift won't actually compile this as it expects that the return type of the function to be applied by the map to be the same as the array's type. Is there any way to map those values to a different type?

Comment: I've made a quick test of your code in a Playground and it [worked](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxhgT3v_71KdaLwyrrnuNShwv2eBTqVXzo). Please add details about the error you get in your case.

Comment: A (minimal) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` closure does not need a return statement.

```
let substrings = ranges.map { (text as NSString).substringWithRange($0) }
```

EDIT: The return statement appears to be implicit if you leave it out. So your code should work as it is. What is your error?

Comment: Strange. It wasn't working with the explicit return. Leaving it implicit solved the problem.